# Accessing instance variable in php

Tags: php

I have written this code I want to increment $age value, $age is declared as static variable of class how to access $age varible and increment its value i am learning the basics please help me guyz

```
<?php
class Person{
    public $age;
   public function __construct($initialAge){
          // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
       if($initialAge<0)
       {
           echo"Age is not valid, setting age to 0.\n";
           $age=0;

       }
       else{
           $age=$initialAge;

       }

    }
   public  function amIOld(){
            // Do some computations in here and print out the correct statement to the console 
       if($age<13){
           echo"You are young.\n"; echo $age;
       }
       else if($age>=13 && $age<18)
       {
            echo"You are a teenager.\n";  
       }
       else{
           echo"You are old.\n"; 

       }

    }
   public  function yearPasses(){
          // Increment the age of the person in here
            $age+=1;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try bellow something like this
`$this->age+=1;`

`$this` is point to current class

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: age in solution.php on line 20
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: age in solution.php on line 21
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: age in solution.php on line 35
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: age in solution.php on line 35
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access empty property in solution.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 solution.php(46): Person->yearPasses()
#1 {main}
  thrown in solution.php on line 35

Comment: How can you add this code ? can you please show error line code?

Comment: $this->$age=$age+1;

Comment: remove `$` sign from age .`$this->age=$this->age+1;`

Comment: Can you check after remove `$` sign ?

Comment: Glad I could help! :)